# What is the meaning of sentence "straight outta + city + state"

Tags: idioms

What is the meaning of sentence "straight outta + city + state" ?
For example: Straight outta Holland Michigan.

Comment: I was raised in Brooklyn and I can tell you we don’t talk like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a slang term that blew up with the release of the movie Straight Outta Compton. It just means that whoever said it grew up in said area. If I say, "Ayy, wuss poppin' B? **I'm straight outta Brooklyn** b. Check out my timbs B. YErrrrrrr," then my "straight outta" statement, along with additional context, such as "Yerrrrr," would reveal that I was raised in Brooklyn, New York.